# How to enable a UIBarItem after checking a TextField is not empty

Tags: ios, swift3

This is my first question in this forum. I would like to know how to enable a UIBarButtonItem only if a UITextField has text in it. I have seen many examples of how to do this in Swift 2 but not Swift 3. This is for a simple app to save some data to core data. I do not have any code to show other then the UIOutlets etc as I am unsure how to check the UITextField for text on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check length of textField.

```
//MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if let text = exampleTextFiled.text {
        exampleBarButtonItem.isEnabled = text.characters.count > 0
    }
}
```

At the top of you controller you need to add `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var exampleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var exampleBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

    // Your code 
}
```

And in the storyboard you can ctrl-drag from textField to controller to add delegate.

Comment: @ P.Pawlus So after looking at three answers I have found a solution. I followed your code but I couldn't get it to work but I might not be understanding your solution fully. What I did was added an @IBAction action from the Text Field in the Scene to the controller for the action Editing Changed and used your above to enable or disable the BarButton.

Comment: @TerryLadden Don't add @IBAction to textField, you need to add just @IBOutlet and delegate. You can do this by ctrl-dragging from text field to `View Contrller` (yellow circle above your controller in storyboard). You need to chose your name of @IBOutlet and delegate. If you don't now how to do this it should help: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html  - Part: Create Outlets for UI Elements

Comment: I have read the documentation and understand how all this works a lot better. Thank you. I love this learning process. However while your solution will work once I have finished entering text into the text field what I would like to do is validate that there is text in the textfield while I am typing and have the save button enabled only when there is text in the text field as I type. Like I posted in my answer I can do that using an IBOutlet but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it using the textfield as a delegate. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's why I don't recommend using Interface Builder and Storyboards, the developer gets "dumbed down".

Anyhow, the algorithm is something like this:

1) Text fields have callback methods or "delegate" methods for text field events like user tapping on the return/done key.

So firstly, you need to tell your text field the delegate is your view controller.

2) You define the necessary UITextField delegate methods (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate)

3) There is a `hasText` method (newly available for iOS 10+) for UITextField to tell if your text field has any text. If there is, enable the bar button item, otherwise disable it.

You could alternatively use `if let` optional binding to unwrap your `textField.text?` property, then check the `text.characters.count` is greater than 0 like so:

```
if let text = textField.text {
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = text.characters.count > 0
}
```

This is the conventional way of doing it (before iOS 10 if you want to support older iOS version) :D

The code in full is below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var myTextField:UITextField!

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // self is referring to this view controller
        ...
        myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        myTextField.delegate = self
    }

    // UITextField Delegate Methods
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        // get the navigation bar button (right bar button in my case)
        // and set its "isEnabled" property depending on whether
        // the textField has any text using "hasText" of UITextField
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = textField.hasText
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        hideKeybaord()

        return false
    }

    // UITouches delegate methods for extra user experience polish
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        // hides keyboard when user taps on the background
        hideKeybaord()
    }

    // resusable hideKeyboard method
    func hideKeybaord() {
        myTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        // in case you need to hide all other text fields in the future
        // textField2.resignFirstResponder()
        // textField3.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and code, at the moment I am just using the Hardware keyboard to enter text so I will be looking at your code to work with the iOS keyboard

Comment: Hardware keyboard? Are you building some sort of app that make use of 3rd party keyboards from Logitech for example?

Comment: No, not building app to make use of 3rd party keyboard. I am learning Swift and I am just making a simple app to learn core data etc.. I am using the simulator hardware keyboard to input text. Next I will consider using the onscreen keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I implemented to resolve my problem. It does not take into consideration the iOS keyboard. The last function is the @IBAction (Editing Changed) added to the controller (ViewController.swift) from the TextField in the Scene. I right clicked the TextField in the scene selected the Action, Editing Changed and dragged it to the View Controller. Thanks to all for your iuput and code!!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

   // Add Outlet
   @IBOutlet weak var tvShowName: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!


   // Add functions

   @IBAction private func saveButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

      let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
      let newTVShow = TVShows(context: context)

      newTVShow.name = tvShowName.text

      do {
         try context.save()
         navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
      } catch {
         let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Failed to save the TV Show", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
         alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
         self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
   }

   @IBAction private func cancelButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
      // Code for cancel
      navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      saveButton.isEnabled = false
   } 

   @IBAction func tvShowTextFieldEditChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
      if let text = tvShowName.text{
          saveButton.isEnabled = text.characters.count > 0
      }
   }
}
```